# How to Keep Text Consistent in A Shell Script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Good Day!

I am creating a Shell Script so I can then use it to do X (Won't tell)

This is my Current Script

```
clear
echo Ahmad A Kazi
echo IDNO: BD_3456
echo 
echo Data Clear Program
echo c 2015 Ahmad A Kazi
echo
echo First Update
echo 
apt-get update
echo
echo Purge Programs
echo
apt-get purge cmake -y
apt-get purge libtool -y
apt-get purge libcurl4-openssl-dev -y
apt-get purge libjansson-dev -y
```

This is Just Part of The Script because rest is Proprietary

I want this to be there on top of the Script Output and not Change it's position the Whole Time, this text below should be consistently on the Top The Whole Time

```
===========================================
Ahmad A Kazi
Copyright 2015, The DNACoin Developers

===========================================
```

For Example

```
===========================================
Ahmad A Kazi
Copyright 2015, The DNACoin Developers

===========================================

Some thing else is going on......
```

This Something Else should not end up Removing My Name and Copyright
Also, how to print Time and keep on self updating....

Please help!

Thank You

Comment: I developed a way to do it, but it's proprietary.

Comment: Please clarify, you want the `===========================================
Ahmad A Kazi
Copyright 2015, The DNACoin Developers

===========================================` at the beginning of every script..thats it?

Comment: OP wants his name and copyright message to stay on top the whole time, while the rest of the scrip runs bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my script. It uses tput cup Y-location X-location and continuously  places that info on top of the screen using while loop. You might wanna adjust it for your application but the point is clear. Now give me 3.50$ because this script is copyrighted **;)**

```
#!/bin/sh

clear
while true; do
clear
tput cup 0 0 
printf  "===========\n SERG KOLO \n================Copyright 2015\n=================="
sleep 1
tput cup 10 10
echo TEST line one of script
echo "Do you love Ubuntu ? "
read answer 
case $answer in

    y) echo " Have a cookie :3  ";;
    n) echo " Go away, Windows lover  ";;
    *) echo  only y or n ;;
esac

sleep 1

df -h

sleep 1

free -h
sleep 1


done
```

[image]

Comment: Do you accept bitcoins? (I'm serious)

Comment: It's Bit's or Nothing!

Comment: @DeOxyRiboseAcid Thank you, but since I don't know how to use bitcoins, I'll pass. Besides, this task wasn't that complicated to achieve, so I don't quite feel right about taking payment for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Create a function just for this script.
mydashes='===================='
function mycls() {
    clear 
    echo $mydashes
    echo Ahmad A Kazi 
    echo Copyright 2015 
    echo $mydashes
    }


mycls
echo Doing stuff
sleep 2
mycls
echo Doing more stuff
sleep 2
mycls
echo Almost done.
sleep 2
echo Done
```

There are other ways, like using ANSI codes, but they get very messy, very quickly. This is simple and quick.

Comment: Thank you, but I execute apt-get update so It lists a long string of URL's, I need my Name to be Consistent

Comment: Ok, so the single command `apt-get` outputs a lot of lines, many more than in my example, so what you need is a true windowing system to keep your name at the top of the screen, and I don't think a shell can do that on its own. You need a windowing system like Perl with Tcl/Tk. This allows you to divide the terminal into scrolling windows. The top window would have your name in multiple lines, the bottom window would have the output of your commands and would scroll while the top window would remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

If the commands output is not essential you could end all commands with `&> /dev/null` all output will be redirected to `/dev/null`.

All info you need to show the user should be like `echo -ne " Purge Programs\r"` in order to always reuse the same line, `\r` makes the cursor return to first column.

```
clear
echo Ahmad A Kazi
echo IDNO: BD_3456
echo 
echo Data Clear Program
echo c 2015 Ahmad A Kazi
echo
echo -ne "First Update\r"
apt-get update &>/dev/null
echo -ne "Purge Programs\r"
apt-get -y purge cmake libtool libcurl4-openssl-dev libjansson-dev &>/dev/null
```

Comment: Sorry but when Program is launched... The Name Goes

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. See if added example works for you.